Updating FCM token in background
I've been struggling with issues related to FCM tokens for a while, and I would really appreciate it if someone could explain how it works.
The Firebase token tells the notification server which device it corresponds to and where to send the notification. This token can change over time, so it's necessary to inform the server in a timely manner that the device has a new token. I handle this by updating the token every 7 days during each app startup. But how does this work if the user doesn't open the app for more than a week, and the app is completely terminated? I believe that a BackgroundTask could be used for this purpose, but from what I understand, it doesn't work if the app is completely shut down (not just running in the background).
Would the user simply stop receiving notifications if the FCM token changes and they don't open the app for a longer period? How is this typically handled in practice? Thanks.

You won't have to do anything like this. You will still receive the notifications. I only refresh the token when appDidBecomeActive() is called

Are you sure? If my notification server sends a notification to an FCM token that my device no longer uses, how could it possibly be delivered?

So the thing works this way: You open your app, fetch for APNs token, and sync it with your server. As far as my observation, it doesn't change until you reopen the app and execute the Firebase code again from your app delegate.

FCM token that my device no longer uses - How do you think this can happen?

It sounds as though your understadning of how FMC tokens works is potentially incorrect.
FMC tokens live on the google service, and are mapped to your APNS token under the hood. The FCM token is not invalidated until you launch your app and neither is your APNS token, so if a user doesnt open the app for an extended period of time, those tokens remain valid (with a few edge case exceptions).

Oh, I really didn't know that. I couldn't find this explanation anywhere in the documentation, and I'm very grateful to you for it. It seems that I won't need to deal with background tasks for now then. Thank you so much.

As mentioned in the comments, FCM token rotation only happens when the device/app is active. Until such an event, messages will be delivered to whatever token the device/app last registered with.
