How FCM token rotation should be handled when the app is closed?
I am using FCM messages in an Android app. I handle new app token generation implementing the Firebase Service. But if the Google decide to rotate my app token, and my app is not started so that it can handle the new token, to update it on my server, it means that all messages that are send to the last known token will not be delivered as notifications to my app ? If that is the scenario, what strategy should I adopt so that I won't lose messages ?

Token rotation only happens when the device/app is active. Until such an event, messages will be delivered to whatever token the device/app last registered with. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78870683/updating-fcm-token-in-background/78942332#78942332 where this recently came up, and was discussed in the comments.

I read the comments. So, all I have to do is to implement .onNewToken() of the Firebase Service, and they don't change it until the app is opened to handle this event ?
